# zsh - evaluate variable inside `` (command substitution)

Tags: shell, zsh

```
# remove all processes by port
# like killport 8000
killport() {
  kill `lsof -t -i:$1`
}
```

however when I'm trying to run the command I get this

```
killport 8000    
killport:kill:2: not enough arguments
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```sh
killport() {
  local port=$(lsof -t -i:"$1")
  [[ -n $port ]] && kill $port
}
```

Your problem was that if `lsof -t -i:$1` didn't output anything - because nothing happened to be listening at the specified port - the `kill` builtin received *no argument*, causing it to complain.

With the solution above, if the specified port is not in use, there will be *no output*, but the exit code - as reflected in `$?` - will be `1`.